# Fit line chart In lighntingChart

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I have line chart like below , Even when i use setInterval there is lots of padding in the top and bottom sometimes.How do I fit the visible line chart max and min to top and bottom of linechart inside the chart view.

[image]

[image]

In my line chart , my max is around 9345 and min is around 9332... but when I want to setinterval , I still see padding in top

```
axisY.setInterval(series.getYMin(),series.getYMax())
```

I even tried manually

```
axisY.setInterval(9332,9345)
```

But Still lots of padding in top of linechart , like in the image.

Comment: For future reference; the reason why Axis.setInterval( min, max ) might not produce the results one might expect is that it can be immediately overridden by automatic scrolling.
As of 07/2020 [LCJS API documentation](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/axis.html#setinterval), you can disable automatic scrolling with the fourth parameter as in
`Axis.setInterval( min, max, undefined, true ) // disableScrolling = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by storing the values in another array and slicing it to visible range ..and getting min max like this

```
axisY.setScrollStrategy(undefined).setInterval(Math.min(...arr1),Math.max(...arr11))
```